# Send audio from USB to two destinations simultaneously

Tags: usb, splitters

We have a need to split (duplicate) a signal and send the complete signal to two destinations simultaneously.  The case is that we want to record an audio stream uncompressed as part of a study.  One of the constraints on the study is that we do not modify the existing desktop (central IT).  We don't want our agents to have to wear multiple microphones... therefore the spitter idea.

Comment: You can't actually do this directly; USB doesn't have this splitting capability. You'll need to find a workaround.

Comment: Can you explain the hardware that you currently have please? I understand that you can't modify the central desktop, but what is the other device that will be listening to the signal? Is it another computer? Can we modify that in any way? What can you tell us about the microphone? I am assuming it has a USB connector, and as JMY1000 said, you can't split USB devices.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a second computer.  I am not a hardware guy -  but why can't we split USB - is there a two way communication protocol underneath? As alternative there may be a need for headset with two microphone mounts...